# What should we rename the [theorics] tag to?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Right now, we have a tag called [theorics].

"Theorics" is kind of a dubious word. I've never heard the word used anywhere but this very site. [Wiktionary says](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/theoric#English) that the word is "obsolete". [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=theory%2Ctheorics&year_start=1800&year_end=2000) shows that the word "theory" is *over one hundred thousand times* as common as "theorics".

Should we change it to "theory" or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like **theory**.

I recently [made a post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/7861/what-does-hard-for-ai-look-like) and was highly surprised to find out that "theory" wasn't a tag option. I have never heard of the word "theorics" before in my life and only found it by looking at the list of tags. **Edit:** I didn’t even realize it was “theorics,” I thought it was “theoretics” which sounds more like a word to me.

Speaking as a native English speaker whose degrees are in *math* and *philosophy* I feel quite inclined to say that a word for “theory” that I’ve never heard in my life is unlikely to be widely known :P

Comment: Theory would definitely be the optimal replacement.

Comment: Yes. In fact, somehow we have only a "theorics" tag (not "theoretics", really "theorics"), and no tag for "theory" at all!

Comment: @JohnDoucette &Stella I almost wonder if we need a "theoretical" tag in addition to "theory".  (Theory for the serious scientific, and theoretical for the popular questions on subjects such as "AI takeover". Semi-serious here;)

Comment: @DukeZhou I really like the "AI-mythology" tag for things like "AI takeover", and it's already around.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, changing it to "theory" sounds good to me.